# Spinner below accept answer button is misaligned in mobile devices

Tags: bug, mobile-web

When you accept an answer, a loading bar shows up below the check mark. Which is not directly below the check mark but bulging to the right a little. The action is very quick so I decided to stop JavaScript as soon as the loader appears to stop its disappearance and this happens:

[image]

And it never stops. Else it is like this little to the left. Not perfectly aligned:

[image: Sorry the image had to be converted to .gif that's why low fps]

This was tested in Chrome dev tools. Else this behavior was caught in iOS Chrome.
Golden element:

```html
<div class="grid--cell as-center">
  <div class="s-spinner s-spinner__sm" role="alert" aria-busy="true">
    <div style="font-size: 0px; color: transparent; float: left;">loading...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```